# React хранение данных пользователя

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, redux, save

Мне нужно создать форму на React где пользователь может заполнить поле "О себе" как можно организовать хранение текста пользователя? Чтобы при обновлении страницы или при в следующем входе на сайт текст не пропадал

Comment: `localStorage`? База данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких задач используют [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)